# Solaris x86 install on Lenovo nothing happening

Tags: installation, solaris, x86, thinkcentre

All,

I am in the process of creating a DEV box for hosting my projects and I am wanting to install Solaris 11.1 onto a Lenovo Desktop PC .

PC Details:

> ```
> Lenovo M92p Thinkcentre 3227
> Intel Core i5 3rd Gen
> 4Gb Ram
> 500gb HDD (MBR Partition)
> ```

Technical Specs

http://support.lenovo.com/en_GB/product-and-parts/detail.page?DocID=PD024409

Currently the system has a OEM version of Windows 7 installed on it.

---

I downloaded the latest Live image of Solaris from Oracle and burned it using Windows burn utility.

I then boot the DVD using UEFI mode and the GRUB menu displays all the various options to start the Solaris install process.

[image]

No matter which option I choose the install hangs on the black screen saying the OS version and the Copyright notice.

The text cursor is not blinking (has it crashed?)

I found this screenshot which shows what I get (note screenshot is from VM)

[image]

**Things I have done:**

- Flashed the BIOS to latest version
- Tried booting solaris from a live usb
- Reburned the solaris iso image
- Waited an hour to see if it progresses, still same screen
- Booted DVD using Legacy mode

**Things I am going to do:**

- Use a different ISO burner utility
- Test if Linux can boot from PC

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to have a non-EFI disk if you want to use legacy mode.  Is the hdd using a MBR or GPT partition currently?

Comment: How do I find that out, the SATA hardrive is using AHCI mode if that helps?

Comment: Disk Manager would tell you.

Comment: I already knew what type of filesystem you were using.  I am interested if its a MBR or GPT disk.

Comment: Ok I just used DISKPART and it says it is MBR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Lenovo UEFI Bug Only Likes Windows and RHEL](http://linux.slashdot.org/story/12/11/16/1414251/lenovo-uefi-bug-only-likes-windows-and-rhel) :

> It looks like Lenovo only knows of Windows and RHEL where their
>   Thinkcentre M92p desktop is concerned. While [investigating UEFI boot
>   issues](http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/20187.html), Matthew Garrett found the PC's firmware actually checks
>   the descriptive string for the operating system, and will prevent
>   unlisted operating systems from booting.
>
> Garrett writes:
>
> Every UEFI boot entry has a descriptive string. This is used by the
>   firmware when it's presenting a menu to users - instead of "Hard drive
>   0" and "USB drive 3", the firmware can list "Windows Boot Manager" and
>   "Fedora Linux". There's no reason at all for the firmware to be
>   parsing these strings. ... there is a function that compares the
>   descriptive string against "Windows Boot Manager" and appears to
>   return an error if it doesn't match. What's stranger is that it also
>   checks for "Red Hat Enterprise Linux" and lets that one work as well.
>   ... This is, obviously, bizarre. A vendor appears to have actually
>   written additional code to check whether an OS claims to be Windows
>   before it'll let it boot. Someone then presumably tested booting RHEL
>   on it and discovered that it didn't work. Rather than take out that
>   check, they then addded another check to let RHEL boot as well.

So it looks like Lenovo will not let you install Solaris on this model.
You may be obliged to install it in a VM.

Comment: There must be a way to fool Lenovo UEFI, maybe by renaming  the descriptive string to Windows?

Comment: That will have to be done on the DVD before burn. You will need an ISO editor to extract it and a hex editor to scan the boot sector for "Oracle Solaris..." and replace one of them by the exact string used by Windows. Lots of work and time will be needed to acquire the knowledge necessary to achieve all this. Are you sure this is worth it?

Comment: I think I will return this Lenovo p.o.s :)

Answer (score 0):

I am using oios openindiana on a Z170 HD3P from new. Initial install was uneventful and the operating system was almost fully functional. However I then installed windows 10 on a parellel disk and updated the bios to F20. It now stops as discribed. However running on Vb works well from USB. I have tried to install via VB but it only recognises EFI partitions to upload to.I have not tried reloading the firmware F20 or data migration cloning of disks.

Comment: Is this intended as a solution, or are you just describing that you have a similar problem?

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. If you have a new question please [ask your own question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) (referencing this one for context if it helps).